# Sass mixin position sticky

Tags: sass, mixins

This is my first day with SASS, so sorry if this sounds so simple.

I am trying to apply a mixin for `position: sticky;` I currently have:

```
@mixin position($sticky) {
  -webkit-position: $sticky;
     -moz-position: $sticky;
      -ms-position: $sticky;
       -o-position: $sticky;
          position: $sticky;
}

.menu-link{
    z-index: 12;
    @include position($sticky);
}
```

I am getting

> body:before {
>     white-space: pre;
>     font-family: monospace;
>     content: "Error: Undefined variable: \"$sticky\".\A    on line 70

I worked from this example:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

I see I have not defined (10px) or equivalent but don't think there is anything I can put here for position, so I am not sure why I would get undefined variable in this instance.

If I just put `@include position;` I get

> Error: Mixin position is missing argument $sticky.\A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to use `.menu-link { @include position(sticky); }` not `$sticky`. You are trying to use a SASS variable, not the CSS property.

In your example you pulled from, the mixin is looking for the parameter `$radius`. 
The parameter is passed in as 10px, thus in the mixin `$radius = 10px`.

In your code, you are looking for `$sticky`. You attempted to call the mixin with an undefined variable of `$sticky` instead of the parameter, sticky. You can use the variable name, if you've defined it before the mixin is called.

### Example

```
@mixin position($sticky) {
  -webkit-position: $sticky;
  -moz-position: $sticky;
  -ms-position: $sticky;
   -o-position: $sticky;
      position: $sticky;
}

$sticky: sticky;

.menu-link{
  z-index: 12;
  @include position($sticky);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually made a mixin for any position value. The variable name is 'sticky' but it can hold any value. This:

```
@mixin position($sticky) {
  -webkit-position: $sticky;
  -moz-position: $sticky;
  -ms-position: $sticky;
   -o-position: $sticky;
      position: $sticky;
}
```

Is equilavent to:

```
@mixin position($pos) {
  -webkit-position: $pos;
  -moz-position: $pos;
  -ms-position: $pos;
   -o-position: $pos;
      position: $pos;
}
```

It will work for any position value:

```
.menu-link{
  z-index: 12;
  @include position(sticky);
  @include position(relative);
  @include position(absolute);
}
```

If just interested in position: sticky;

```
@mixin stickyPosition {
  -webkit-position: sticky;
  -moz-position: sticky;
  -ms-position: sticky;
   -o-position: sticky;
      position: sticky;
}

.menu-link{
      z-index: 12;
      @include stickyPosition;
}
```

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably clean this up a little by using some browser prefix functions so you dont have to write out the browser prefixes.

```
@mixin prefix($declarations, $prefixes: ()) {
   @each $property, $value in $declarations {
      @each $prefix in $prefixes {
         #{'-' + $prefix + '-' + $property}: $value;
      }
      // Output standard non-prefixed declaration
      #{$property}: $value;
   }
}

.menu {
    &-link {
       @prefix((position: sticky), webkit moz ms o);
       z-index:12;
    }
    // other menu classes
}
```

Comment: btw you can use that mixin for any browser prefix, not only the sticky ;)

Comment: Honestly, your best bet would be to toss this node module into your asset build pipeline. Then you just write normal CSS, tell it what browsers you need to support, and it’ll automatically add prefixed rules as necessary based on caniuse data. It’s also nice for old IE rules, which at times do not simply stick “-ms-“ in front (-ms-flex-pack, for example). https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer This also has the added benefit of not making your output CSS like 5x as long for no reason, if your target browsers have supported the rules for years.